# Seeking very simple TIdCommandHandler conditional response example

Tags: delphi, indy10

Delphi XE2, so Indy 10.

My client sends a command which is processed by a TIdCommandHandler of my TIdCmdTCPServer.

I want to be able to perform some logic and return either a success or fail response and check for that back at the client.

Can someone please point me at a few lines of code as an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's the simplest demo.

[image]

Add an IdCmdTCPServer to your form, and add one command, set its name in the `Command` property,  I originally thought I should handle Response in `OnCommand` event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlers0Command(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
   //ASender.Response.Add('Hello');  // wrong way
   ASender.Reply.SetReply(0,'HELLO');

end;
```

**Update** Remy pointed out I shouldn't be using Response.

So you want to return success or failure, it's traditional to use a numeric result followed by the string value. Each string in the response strings list has an implied end-of-line transmitted back to the client:

```
procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlers0Command(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  if DoSomething then
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(0,'OK')
  else
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(999,'ERROR');

end;
```

The idea with the IdCommandHandler and a CmdTCPServer/Client is that you follow the "RFC" style of protocols, which are ANSI/ASCII text-based.  An RFC-style internet protocol's reply is typically encoded over the wire as text with both a numeric and string value.  `ASender.Response` could be used if you needed to take the content of a string list and return that as the response.

As for the client, a [question here suggests that TIdCmdTcpClient is not the most natural way to build the client for this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060751/should-tidcmdtcpserver-and-tidcmdtcpclient-be-used-together).  From their names, you'd have thought they were made for each other, but it's not exactly.  For most simple TIdCMDTCPServers that you could build, you would find that a plain-vanilla `TIdTCPClient` is the simplest building block to start your client with.

Comment: `ASender.Response` is the wrong property to use. Use `ASender.Reply` instead, eg: `ASender.Reply.SetReply(123, 'FAILURE')`. `Sender.Response` is meant for sending multi-line text that supplements the `ASender.Reply`. Then on the client side, use the `TIdTCPClient.SendCmd()` method and the `TIdTCPClient.LastCmdResult` property to send commands and retrieve the responses.

Comment: +1 to both. Just to be 100% clear ... if I set ASender.Reply then that overrides the "normalResponse" ?  And the client checks for it ... how?  Thanks so much for the help, guys ...

Comment: oops, sorry, I see no that you already answered that. Thanks .. and the answer

Comment: You know it would be cool if Delphi could auto-generate a skeleton handler for these events....  Wouldn't it?  (VCL Event Handler Templates).;